# i can't read image files in this response with nginx

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

In my program, i use symfony2+nginx

I want to show image in WEB with a request.

this is my controller code

```
public function downloadLocalFileAction($filepath)
{
    $response = BinaryFileResponse::create($filepath, 200, [], false);
    $response->trustXSendfileTypeHeader();

    $mimeType = $this->getMimeTypeByExtension(substr(strrchr($filepath, '.'), 1));

    if ($mimeType) {
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', $mimeType);
    }

    return $response;
}

public static function getMimeTypeByExtension($extension)
{
    $mimes = array(
        'gif'  => 'image/gif',
        'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'jpg'  => 'image/jpeg',
        'png'  => 'image/png'
    );

    return empty($mimes[$extension]) ? null : $mimes[$extension];
}
```

my nginx conf is

```
location / {
    index app.php;
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/udisk {
    internal;
    root /Users/yearnwilling/htdocs/wellzhiot/app/data/;
}

location ~ ^/(app|app_dev)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS              off;
    fastcgi_param  HTTP_X-Sendfile-Type X-Accel-Redirect;
    fastcgi_param  HTTP_X-Accel-Mapping /udisk=/Users/yearnwilling/htdocs/wellzhiot/app/data/udisk;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
}

location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|swf)$ {
    expires 3y;

    access_log off;

    gzip off;
}
```

when i asked for this request,return a nginx 500 error,

> [error] 9976#0: *27 open() "/Users/yearnwilling/htdocs/wellzhiot/web/Users/yearnwilling/htdocs/wellzhiot/web/files/default/2016/09-02/2016902112541-emyxhm.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: wellzhiot.io, request: "GET /app_dev.php/image/Url/cHVibGljOi8vZGVmYXVsdC8yMDE2LzA5LTAyLzIwMTY5MDIxMTI1NDEtZW15eGhtLnBuZw==

why the root read twice in it

Comment: Have you checked that the file `Users/yearnwilling/htdocs/wellzhiot/web/Users/yearnwilling/htdocs/wellzhiot/web/files/default/2016/09-02/2016902112541-emyxhm.png` really exists? The error indicates, as it is clearly written, that it can't find that file.

Comment: it is an error path with  Users/yearnwilling/htdocs/wellzhiot/web/Users/yearnwilling/h‌​tdocs/wellzhiot/web/‌​files/default/2016/0‌​9-02/2016902112541-e‌​myxhm.png,
the true path is /Users/yearnwilling/h‌​tdocs/wellzhiot/web/‌​files/default/2016/0‌​9-02/2016902112541-e‌​myxhm.png. but i dont know why become it .

Comment: Check where you get the path you're sending to your method. We can't help you with that since we have no idea how or where you get that path. It does looks like your prepending the absolute file path with the absolute root path.

Comment: at the return of downloadLocalFileAction,the response only have absolute file path, but on browser(chrome) to read this file ,it be added root path.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are doing and what you are trying to do here. What is your script suppose to do? Send a file for download? Then you either point the browser to the relative (from the document root) path to the file. If the file is outside the document root, or you want to force download, you need to read the file content and output it to the browser. The browser should never get the absolute server path to the file.

Comment: maybe i have some idea，Thanks lot